# JLabel getToolTipText() not returning tooltips that have been set

Tags: java, swing, tooltip, jlabel

So i'm working on something that will find the locations of Jlabels on the screen so i can use these positions to generate data later at these points depending on what type of point it is.

To keep track of specific points, i have set the tooltip of the important labels to certain text so i can add them to a `Map<String, Rectangle>`. The rectangle will give its location on the screen, as well as the size of the label. This will be used to generate the positioning for my data points.

The problem right now is that I am not getting any strings that ive set, using the `getToolTipText()` on the JLabels.

```
public Map<String, Rectangle> positions() {        
    Map<String, Rectangle> ioPoints = new HashMap<>();
    return positions(mainPanel, ioPoints);
}

// Runs through each component starting from the mainPanel which contains everything
// Only labels have tooltips
public Map<String, Rectangle> positions(Container p1, Map<String, Rectangle> ioPoints) {

    for (Component p : p1.getComponents()) {

        if (p instanceof JLabel) {

            try {

                if (((JLabel) p).getToolTipText() != null) {
                    // Never hit at all???
                    System.out.println("Has a tooltip:" + ((JLabel) p).getToolTipText());
                    Rectangle r = p.getBounds();
                    Component par = p;
                    while (par.getParent() != mainPanel) {
                        par = par.getParent();
                    }
                    r = SwingUtilities.convertRectangle(par, r, mainPanel);
                    //Point spot = ((JLabel) p).getLocation();
                    ((JLabel) p).setText("x=" + r.getX() + ", y=" + r.getY());
                    Rectangle oldRect = ioPoints.put(((JLabel) p).getToolTipText(), r);
                    if (oldRect != null) {
                        System.out.println("Replaced " + ((JLabel) p).getToolTipText()
                                + ".\nOld rectangle " + oldRect.toString()
                                + "\nNew rectangle: " + r.toString());
                    }
                    //System.out.println("Position: " + spot.toString() + "\tr: " + r.toString());
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException | IllegalComponentStateException e) {
                System.out.println("Error with " + ((JLabel) p).getName());
            }
        } else {
            if (p instanceof JPanel) {
                return positions((Container) p, ioPoints);
            }
        }
    }

    return ioPoints;

}
```

Example code of where i set tooltips.

```
tooltip = new String[]{"Comp Amps Temp " + rack.getName() + " `%sgname` `%compname`"};

for (int i = 0; i < numSg; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < comp[i]; j++) {
        label = new JLabel("");
        label.setToolTipText(tooltip[0]
                .replace("`%sgname`", rack.getSuctionGroupNameIndex(i))
                .replace("`%compname`", rack.getSuctionGroupIndex(i).getCompressorNameIndex(j)));
        label.setFont(font);
        label.setOpaque(true);
        label.setBorder(border);
        label.setBackground(Colours.BlueLight.getCol());
        panel.add(label, c);
        c.gridx += 1;
    }
}
```

[image: Tooltip showing on JPanel]

Any ideas why `jlabel.getToolTipText();` wont give me any values for tool tips I've clearly set.

Comment: Have you tried the `name` property  ([Component.setName()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setName%28java.lang.String%29) - [Component.getName()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getName%28%29)) instead, just to see if the problem is not with setting the properties in the tooltiptext but somewhere else in your logic?

Comment: I redid my implementation so instead of using tool tips and using this function, i just added each label with a string in a Map. I use the map latter to access the label and i have the string so it works much better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you just create a class that extends JLabel like so:

```
public class ToolTippedJLabelOrWhateverYouWantToCallIt extends JLabel {
    String tooltip = null;
    @Override
    public void setToolTipText(String text) {
        tooltip = text;
        super.setToolTipText(text);
    }
    @Override
    public String getToolTipText() {
        return tooltip;
    }
}
```

There might be another way to get the tooltip text, but this is just a simple way.